# ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

Tags: oracle, websphere

1- this error is in was logs. Nothing in alert log from server side (11.2.0.4)

2- the error talks about distributed transactions. There's no such thing. There's no dblink from or to the database.

I searched the web and oracle support the whole day. All talk about distributed transactions using dblink and increasing DISTRIBUTED_LOCK_TIMEOUT parameter set to default value 1 mn.

but there's no db link or distant access. There's only 2 websphere nodes for load balancing.

3 - there's no blocking issues. The problem happened when no activity on database.

Comment: Edit your post to include whether you're asking about traditional or Liberty, the  app server version and the actual text of the log.  If you're getting that error, something is configured to use a datasource with an Oracle jdbc provider, look at both in the admin console.  Also look for things like persistent EJB timers, schedulers, work managers and job managers, all may be configured to access databases.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when booth WAS nodes are not synchronized

Ripple start solves the problem